# How to use a multiple datasource with many laguage in grails 3.3

Tags: grails

i try to connect mi graills 3.3.9 in a many database: 1 main datasource in posgrest, a slave datasource to back up in sqlite , and a 3th datasoruce mongoDb for a log.
The problem is when i try to save a domain class in sqlite data source, this is not detect (alone or with other).

This is my application.yml:

```
 hibernate:
 cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: false
    use_query_cache: false


dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
        username: "postgres"
        password: "postgres"


IkebanaUser:
     pooled: true
     driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
     username: ''
     password: ''

grails:
    mongo:
    host: "localhost"
    port: 27017
    username: "admin"
    password: "admin"
    databaseName: "IkebanaERP"


environments:
   development:
      dataSource:
          dbCreate: update
          url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP

      dataSources:
          Ikebana:
             grails:
              mongodb:
                  connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/IkebanaERP"


      IkebanaUser:
             url: jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser
             dbCreate: update

test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP

production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

and this is my domain class

```
class Usuario {

  String nombre
  String  apellido

  static constraints = {
    nombre  nullable: true
    apellido unique: true
      }
static mapping = {
  datasource 'IkebanaUser'}
}
```

And lunch this error:

```
  "Exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.exceptions.ConfigurationException:   DataSource not found for name [IkebanaUser] in configuration. Please check your multiple data sources configuration and try again."
```

If you put in domain class:

```
  datasources(['DEFAULT', 'IkebanaUser'])
```

only using to save in the DEFAULT  datasource ( the postgres dasource)
Whats is wrong with this code?
thanks

Comment: If you have multiple datasources configured (like `datasources(['DEFAULT', 'IkebanaUser'])`) the first one in the list is the default.  For example, if you invoke `Usuario.list()` that will query the default data source.  If you invoke `Usuario. IkebanaUser.list()` that will query the `IkebanaUser` data source.  Can you you show the code that you are using to initiate a query?

Comment: There is an unintentional space character in my previous comment and I don't think the system will let me edit it now.  `Usuario. IkebanaUser.list()` was supposed to be `Usuario.IkebanaUser.list()`.

Comment: More info is available at https://gorm.grails.org/7.0.5/hibernate/manual/index.html#multipleDataSources.

Comment: i try save a object Usuarios , see the Controller   class UsuarioController {
   
def index() {
       def b = new Usuario(nombre: "Sorrento", apellido: "Sama")
       System.out.println(b.nombre)
       b.save()
       b.save(flush: true)
       def c = new Usuario(nombre: "Carolino",apellido: "Ruty")
       c.save()
       c.save(flush: true)                                                                                                      if i try to code def b = new Usuario(nombre: "Sorrento", apellido: "Sama")
       b.IkebanaUser.save()    this code no run /* see the picture

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LDNyfWas85WPImXLMgUt0YAzptShS0BZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The call to `b.IkebanaUser.save()` at https://github.com/jeffbrown/robertoriartemultipledatasources/blob/ca01563e95faff459a939daf63d7fb7fc41f0f8d/grails-app/services/robertoriartemultipledatasources/HelperService.groovy#L10 appears to work fine.

Comment: FYI... Sharing a link to a code project is often better than sharing a screenshot of code.

Comment: Thak you bro !!! It work with this line  compile group: 'com.zsoltfabok', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '1.0'     and your answers!!!My best regarts !!!

Comment: " It work with this line compile group: 'com.zsoltfabok', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '1.0' and your answers" - I am surprised that the code you shared works with any version of `sqlite-dialect` but I am glad that the issue is worked out.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
IkebanaUser:
     pooled: true
     driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
     username: ''
     password: ''
```

That should be a child of `dataSources`, like this:

```
dataSources:
    IkebanaUser:
         pooled: true
         driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
         username: ''
         password: ''
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be wrong in the project.  All that I see wrong in the code you have shown is the config problem described above.  If you could send a PR to https://github.com/jeffbrown/robertoriartemultipledatasources/blob/ca01563e95faff459a939daf63d7fb7fc41f0f8d/grails-app/services/robertoriartemultipledatasources/HelperService.groovy#L10 which demonstrates the problem I would be happy to help remedy that for you.  Best of luck.

Comment: this the class of the code https://github.com/marcosRiarte/StackOVerFlowMultipleDataSource/tree/main

Comment: Lunch this error : nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment],  thank a lot;

Comment: "this the class of the code github.com/marcosRiarte/StackOVerFlowMultipleDataSource/tree/… " - One issue is the way your transaction management isn't being done.  If you can put that code in a runnable Grails app similar to the one I linked above, I would be happy to send you a PR indicating how to make it work.  The code in the repo I linked above does work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is was many

build graddle need

```
  compile group: 'com.zsoltfabok', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '1.0'
```

and the controller metod need @Transactional("IkebanaUser") like jeff said and save the object b.IkebanaUser.save(flush:true) then look this

```
 class UsuarioController {
   @Transactional("IkebanaUser")
    def index() {
       Usuario b = new Usuario(nombre:"Mañana", apellido: "ros" )
       System.out.println(b.apellido)
       b.IkebanaUser.save(flush:true)
   }
```

and application.yml  look that like jeef said

```
dataSource:
   pooled: true
   jmxExport: true
   driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
   username: "postgres"
    password: "postgres"

dataSources:
    IkebanaUser:
           pooled: true
           driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
           username: ''
          password: ''

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
           dbCreate: update
           url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP

    dataSources:
        IkebanaUser:
            url: jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser
            dbCreate: update
test:
    dataSource:
        url: jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser
        dbCreate: update
production:
    dataSource:
        url: jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser
        dbCreate: update
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
   ..........
```

Comment: See too https://www.programmersought.com/article/96096179732/ for use of many databases!!! Thnks a lot!!